# Keep image centered after updating x with mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script that moves an image slightly to the left or right when the user moves their mouse. The problem is this image is always in the top left of my window when I need it to always stay in the center.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<img id="logo" src="logoHeader.png" style="position:absolute;" />
</body>

<script lang="javascript">

function updateLogoPosition( e )
{
    var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
    var m = e.x / 12;
    logo.style.left = m + "px";
}

document.onmousemove = updateLogoPosition;

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: so where your image should be now?

Comment: I want it to appear centered. So when the mouse moves it moves the same x amount as the mouse but remains centered.

Comment: So you want your image vertically centered ?

Comment: Horizontally centered. When the mouse moves it moves the image slightly to the left or to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to do some more calculation to do this.

You need to know the width and height of the viewport to find the middle. Then you need to normalise the mouse position so that you calculate the offset from the centre line not from the top left as you e.x was doing.

Something like this should do it, where "modifier" will allow you to change the violence of the offset.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<img id="logo" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" style="position:absolute;" />

<script>

    window.onload = setInitialLogoPosition;
    document.onmousemove = updateLogoPosition;


    function setInitialLogoPosition(){ 

        var bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
        var logoWidth = logo.width;
        var logoHeight = logo.height;
        var leftOffset = (bodyWidth/2 - logoWidth/2); 
        var topOffset = (bodyHeight/2 - logoHeight/2);

        logo.style.left = leftOffset;
        logo.style.top = topOffset;

    }

    function updateLogoPosition( e ){

        // Get height and width of body
        var bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight; 
        var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;

        // Get height and width of logo
        var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
        var logoWidth = logo.width;
        var logoHeight = logo.height;

        /* Normalise the mouse so that 0 is the centre 
        with negative values to the left and positive to the right */
        var x = (e.x / bodyWidth * 100) - 50;
        var y = (e.y / bodyHeight * 100) - 50;

        // Calculate the position of the logo without mouse manipulation
        var leftOffset = (bodyWidth/2 - logoWidth/2); 
        var topOffset = (bodyHeight/2 - logoHeight/2);

        // Set violence of offset 
        var modifier = 0.5;

        // Add the mouse offset to the central position
        leftOffset += (x * modifier); 
        topOffset += (y * modifier);


        // Apply the calculated position to the logo
        logo.style.left = leftOffset + "px";
        logo.style.top = topOffset + "px";
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Works perfectly. Thank you very much!!

Comment: One small issue is that when the page first loads the image is located in the top left area of the screen until you mouse over the page. How can I get it to start centered?

Comment: You can add `window.onload = updateLogoPosition;` that will call your function for the first time when the page loads.

Comment: Still seems to stay in the top left with that in there.

Comment: Where did you put it? I have edited my answer to show you where it should be pasted.

Comment: In the same place as your example.

Comment: Ok, if you refresh without the mouse inside the window element it fails and doesn't set the initial value. To fix this I have added another initial set function which is not reliant on the cursor.

Comment: More than welcome. I have been in your shoes doing stuff like that many a time. I know how frustrating it can be. Keep plugging away.

Answer (score 0):

To center horizontally you can do it with CSS:

```
<img id="logo" src="logoHeader.png" style="position:relative; text-algin:center; display: block; margin: 0 auto;" />
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2z31o10y/)

Comment: In the problem description you stated that you already had the script that moved it to the right or left. I assumed your script was working.

Comment: This is almost working, but it only seems to move in one direction (right) now when it should use the center as its point to move either way.